# JQuery TableSorter Not Sorting, Not Working, Does Nothing in MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, tablesorter

Thought I'd share this little gotcha.  I looked high and low for this specific issue and couldn't find the answer.

**What I did wrong**:  When iterating through a collection in your foreach make sure you have your "tbody" tags are placed **outside** of the foreach statement!

Here's what I Have

1. **WaitTimesData.cshtml**:

```html
@model IEnumerable
<SharePointWaitTimesWebMVC5.Models.FeedData>

  @{ ViewBag.Title = "WaitTimesData"; }


  <h2>Wait Times Data</h2>
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Id
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>

        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Park
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Status
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Opens
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Wait
        </th>

        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">

          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Modified)
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {

      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>

        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_UO_Park)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Content_Status)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Opens_At)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Wait_Time)
        </td>

        <td style="padding:5px;">


          @DateTime.Parse(item.Modified).ToLocalTime()


        </td>

      </tr>

      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
  }
```

2. **_Layout.cshtml**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - SharePoint Wait Times Feed</title>

  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("SharePoint Wait Times Feed", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Feed Data", "WaitTimesData", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("JSON Data", "WaitTimesJsonData", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Share Point Wait Times Feed</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerytable") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {

        $('.table').tablesorter();
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

3. **BundleConfig.cs**:

```html
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

           

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerytable").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"
               ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The community appreciates people sharing details about errors that are encountered, but in order to maximize the usefulness to future visitors, please change up your format a bit. Instead of putting "solved" in the title, it would be better to separate your question and solution. Phrase your question and title as if you didn't know the answer at all; then answer it down in the answers section. A much more descriptive title than "Not sorting, not working, does nothing" will help others find it more easily.

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages people to answer their own questions if they can, but questions and answers should definitely be separated, and marking your own answer as "accepted" is preferred over using "solved" like other forums. Thanks for taking the time to share this!

Comment: This helped me so much! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

```html
@model IEnumerable
<SharePointWaitTimesWebMVC5.Models.FeedData>

  @{ ViewBag.Title = "WaitTimesData"; }


  <h2>Wait Times Data</h2>
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Id
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>

        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Park
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Status
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Opens
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          Wait
        </th>

        <th style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">

          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Modified)
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {

      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>

        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_UO_Park)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Content_Status)
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Opens_At)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WTB_Wait_Time)
        </td>

        <td style="padding:5px;">


          @DateTime.Parse(item.Modified).ToLocalTime()


        </td>

      </tr>

      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
  }
```